# Trying to use IntStream.range() and getting "This static method can only be accessed..."

Tags: java, java-8, iterator, java-stream

I am using IBM JVM 8 and Eclipse. I want an iterator over a range of integers.

So I try to use IntStream.range() and get a weird error. I have now removed the iterator part to get a minimal example of the problem. This line causes an error:

```
IntStream range = IntStream.range(0,max);
```

The error is: This static method of interface IntStream can only be accessed as IntStream.range

But isn't this how I am accessing it already? How can I get it to work without producing errors?

(Of course I can use a loop instead of an iterator, but the iterator would be neater).

Comment: check IDE compiler is Java8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Referring to the [IntStream java doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html) and [Compatibility Guide for JDK 8](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8-compatibility-guide-2156366.html)
`Interface IntStream` is only brought up since Java 1.8.
Use compliance from execution environment 'JavaSE-1.8' on the Java Build Path and rebuild the project.

Comment: Thanks, this has helped. Java standard library was 1.8 but compliance was, by mistake, 1.7.